# My comparator's compare method isn't working

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have a Customer object class which has some variables and is implementing a Comparator already regarding one of those variables. However I need to implement another Comparator for a different variable last_name.

Since I can't have 2 compareTo() methods in my Customer class I decided to make a Comparing class specifically for this here

```
public class CompareByLastName implements Comparator<Customer> {

    private List<Purchase> purchases;
    private List<Customer> customers;

    public CompareByLastName(List<Purchase> purchases, List<Customer> customers) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
        this.customers = customers;
    }

    /**
     * @param descending
     * @return will be a sorted, in ascending, or descending, array of customer's according to their authors.
     */
    public List<Purchase> sortByLastName(boolean descending){

        List<Purchase> return_List = new LinkedList<Purchase>();

        Collections.sort(customers);

        if(descending == true) {
            Collections.reverse(customers);
        }

        for(Customer customer : customers) {
            for(Purchase purchase_info : purchases) {
                if(customer.getId() == purchase_info.getCustomer_id()) {
                    return_List.add(purchase_info);
                }
            }
        }

        return return_List;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Customer customer_1, Customer customer_2) {

        int result = customer_1.getLastName().compareTo(customer_2.getLastName());

        if(result < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(result > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

but once it hits Collections.sort(customers);

it doesn't activate the public int compare(Customer customer_1, Customer customer_2) below.

Frankly I don't know what its using as a comparator in the sort; does anyone know how to fix this problem and get it sorting by the last_name?

Oh and once it gets to return it some how manages to go from 100(0-99) items  in purchases to 103(0-102) items in return list? No idea how that's happening.

*fixed this part I had switch the for loops reading Purchase then going through the list of all the customers and finding matches instead of vise versa.*

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your comparator's `compare` method isn't working because you're not passing an instance of your comparator to `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your `compare` method.

```
    Collections.sort(customers);
```

The line above sort customers by their natural order (as defined by `Customer.compareTo()`), not according to your comparator. Instead you may do this:

```
    Collections.sort(customers, this);
```

Now your `CompareByLastName` will be use as comparator in the sorting.

A couple of asides:

- Your design with the sort method in the comparator class is unconventional. It should work, though.
- In your `compare` method you don’t need the if-else construct. The following much simpler implementation suffices:

  ```
     return customer_1.getLastName().compareTo(customer_2.getLastName());
  ```

Comment: Thank you :D I tried a bunch of second params in .sort() it never occurred to me that the this keyword would work.

Comment: @Mike_1234 the reason, why the solution was not obvious to you, is that your entire design is counter-intuitive. You should not mix the `Comparator` implementation with the code performing the sort operation. In fact, you don’t need to implement the comparator yourself. Just `Collections.sort(customers, Comparator.comparing(Customer::getLastName));` would work. Or even simpler, `customers.sort(Comparator.comparing(Customer::getLastName));`. But actually, that’s not what you want. Your goal is to sort the *purchase list*, so you should do that &avoid the nested loop that performs n×m operations

Comment: @Mike_1234 i.e. `public static List<Purchase> sortPurchaseByCustomersLastName(List<Customer> customers, List<Purchase> purchases, boolean descending) { List<Purchase> returnList = new ArrayList<>(purchases); Map<Object,String> idToName = customers.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getId, Customer::getLastName)); Comparator<Purchase> c = Comparator.comparing(p -> idToName.get(p.getCustomer_id())); if(descending) { c = c.reversed(); } returnList.sort(c); return returnList; }`. Also recommended read: [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488)